# Asp.Net Asp Menu changing the order of the selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspmenu

I have an aspmenu in my site and I'm applying the "selected" atribute for the item who has the same url than the actual page so I can apply the StaticSelectedStyle to the item.

The problem is that the selected item (or item group) on menu is always in the first position in the menu, changing the original position (that needs to be controled).

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Can you show your ASPX markup for the `<asp:Menu />` and how you are determining the "item who has the same url than the actual page"?

Comment: It seems that the problem are resolved by itself.
I only change e few parameters and the items order didn't change anymore.

Thanks for the reply.